# How to check for existence of object in Roblox with lua?

Tags: if-statement, lua, label, roblox

I am trying to code a gui that is dynamically assigned. I have four teams. I am getting stuck at a certain point. I want to make a function that, when a player joins the game, checks if the other teams have already scored to update their labels. It looks like this:

```
local function updateAllLabelsLateArrival(redPoints, bluePoints, yellowPoints, greenPoints)

    game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.ReallyRedTeam.Points.Text = redPoints
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.ReallyBlueTeam.Points.Text = bluePoints 
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.NewYellerTeam.Points.Text = yellowPoints
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.LimeGreenTeam.Points.Text = greenPoints

end
```

The function is remotely triggered from a server-side script when a player joins. The problem I have is that not all four labels might exist. Suppose a green team player joins in when there is only a red team player already playing. It will come back with the error

```
ReallyBlueTeam is not a valid member of ScreenGui
```

I thought wrapping each line in an if statement to check if the label exists, like so:

```
if game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.ReallyRedTeam then game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.ReallyRedTeam.Points.Text = redPoints end
```

But this is giving the same error. So my question is, how do I check that a label has been created before updating the points? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a localcsript, you can use WaitForChild() which will yield until the label has been created!

```
game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("ScreenGui"):WaitForChild("ReallyRedTeam"):WaitForChild("Points").Text = redPoints
```

More information about WaitForChild [here](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/WaitForChild)!

Alternatively, if you don't know for definite they will be created, you can use FindFirstChild. This won't yield.

```
if game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui:FindFirstChild("ReallyRedTeam") then
    print("it exists")
end
```

More information about FindFirstChild [here](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/FindFirstChild)!
Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem with WaitForChild here is that it will pause the entire script until another player joins the blue team which could never happen if it's a quiet server

Comment: @Taazar not if this is in a localcsript

Comment: Local or global script has no impact on it. A red player has to join before "ReallyRedTeam" exists as a child of "ScreenGui". If a red player does not join then your code will wait forever, never progressing to the next line of code unless you have specified a timeout

Comment: Yes, and that's a problem because?

Comment: @Corsaka It's a problem because until a red player joins, neither the blue, yellow or green points will show up either because the program can't reach the code that shows them. (Also in the future, make sure to tag the person you are responding to in the comments otherwise there's no notification. I only saw your comment by chance.)

Comment: Ah, so specifically only red, not any of the others. @Taazar Cheers.

Comment: @Corsaka It depends on the way the code is ordered. Currently no reds will stop all 4 showing, no blues will stop blue, yellow and green from showing, no yellows stops yellow and green from showing and no greens stops only greens from showing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them all on one line each then the best to use would be `FindFirstChild()` as @jjwood1600 has said. I would also recommend making use of a variable to shorten your GUI paths as you can see below:

```
local function updateAllLabelsLateArrival(redPoints, bluePoints, yellowPoints, greenPoints)

    local userGui = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui
    if userGui:FindFirstChild("ReallyRedTeam") then userGui.ReallyRedTeam.Points.Text = redPoints end
    if userGui:FindFirstChild("ReallyBlueTeam") then userGui.ReallyBlueTeam.Points.Text = bluePoints end
    if userGui:FindFirstChild("NewYellerTeam") then userGui.NewYellerTeam.Points.Text = yellowPoints end
    if userGui:FindFirstChild("LimeGreenTeam") then userGui.LimeGreenTeam.Points.Text = greenPoints end

end
```

In normal Lua you can indeed do the if statements the way you did where you don't use `FindFirstChild` but Roblox's own version RBX.Lua doesn't.